# Trivia questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Are trivia questions off topic?

[This newest question about BMW cruise control led me to wonder](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15933/when-was-cruise-control-first-standard-in-the-bmw-3-series).

Comment: I cam here for the same reason. How would this have something to do with maintenance or repair?

Comment: I recommend editing the link to be just the question link so people finding this question later aren't confused.

Comment: @Paul ... I'm sorry for being dense, but I'm not quite sure what you are suggesting in your second comment.

Comment: I think he means the change I just made...

Comment: @NickC ... I'm good with that :D

Comment: [See the meta post here](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1328/85)

Comment: Well ^ that was rhetorical lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call them trivia questions. When I saw the question in question I came to meta to make a case for having that question be on topic.

They are good for the Q&A format we have here, it's useful information that would bring traffic here.

I think question like the BMW cruise control as well as the following questions should be on topic

Did the 1954 Chevrolet Truck 6 cyl 235 ci come with an oil filter from the factory?

Did all 1955 Chevrolet Bel Air have positive traction, or was it an option?

[Paulster2](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4152/paulster2) Could answer most F-Body questions like this off the top of his head and [Bob Cross](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/57/bob-cross) and [Roy Alsop](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/37/rory-alsop) could answer most Subaru questions like this of the top of theirs. Who am I kidding [Bob Cross](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/57/bob-cross) could answer ALL the questions of the top of his head with a BCWOW.

While these questions might seem trivial I think they would provide a good resource for future visitors.

Of course that's just my opinion, I could be wrong.

Comment: I see your point. I'm just not liking the idea of getting down in those weeds like that. At what point would something like that *get too far* into the weeds? Maybe if the OP had put some context behind it I would like the question more? Like, *I have a 3 Series BMW I'd like to add cruise control to. Did it come from the factory with it? What was the first year it was utilized for the 3 Series BMW?* At least that way it would have some meaning and not just a random trivia looking question.

Comment: @Paulster2 Agreed, the question could have been written better, but I think the question in general should be on topic. What if someone was trying to confirm what was standard on the car? Trying to find the correct oil filter housing for the 54 truck, and not realizing it was a Sears add on filter because it didn't come from the factory with an oil filter. I realize context matters, but the question was closed because it was off-topic, not because it was poorly written.

Comment: The OP did state he is going to add some context to it a little later on, so I'm eagerly anticipating their return. If the question comes out better, I will petition you to reopen. This does beg the question, though, to what extent would we need to entice the OP to create a better (or more complete) question? What should we ask for or what should we expect before we vote to close something?

Comment: As the asker I can understand why it might be closed. I'll make a meta post later with more context, but closing was probably the better idea if it doesn't seem on topic.

Comment: Slippery slope.